# JSON Parsing to multiple TextView

Tags: java, android, json

I have problem with parsing my JSON Object to multiple textview.

I have a TextView1, TextView2 and TextView3.

I would like to download data from: "max", "min" and "average" and synch data with .settext in TextView1, TextView2 and TextView3

My JSON looks: *{"max":15.6,"min":14.05,"average":14.55}*

My code below:

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            Log.d("Login attempt", connection.toString());
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            String maxPrice = parentObject.getString("max");
            return maxPrice;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

onPostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute (String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        maxPrice.setText(result);
```

I can't add more String and synch in other TextView. That's work only for one TextView. I can't synch multiple TextView. Can you help me?

Comment: why don't you return a list of strings ?

Answer (score 0):

you have two option.

**1st option**

return your whole json string like

```
String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        String finalJson = buffer.toString();
        return finalJson;
```

then process your json on your onPostExecute like

```
protected void onPostExecute (String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(result);
String maxPrice = parentObject.getString("max");
maxPrice.setText(result);
String minPrice = parentObject.getString("min");
minPrice.setText(result);
String avgPrice = parentObject.getString("avg");
avgPrice.setText(result);
}
```

**or**

**2nd option is**

You have to try like this

```
String result = "";
String maxPrice = parentObject.getString("max");
String avgPrice = parentObject.getString("avg");
String minPrice = parentObject.getString("min");
result = maxPrice+","+avgPrice+","+minPrice;
return result;
```

then split it on your onPostExecute

```
protected void onPostExecute (String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String[] separated = result.split(",");
maxPrice.setText(separated[0]);
minPrice.setText(separated[2]);
avgPrice.setText(separated[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Return your `finalJson` from `doInBackground`

2) `getString` & `setText` in `onPostExecute`

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(result);
String maxPrice = parentObject.getString("max");
String minPrice = parentObject.getString("min");
String avg = parentObject.getString("average");
tvMaxPrice.setText(maxPrice);
tvMinPrice.setText(minPrice);
tvAvg.setText(avg);
```